# QGIS exported PDF not the same as Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pdf

Trying to export a finished map to .pdf - view is correct in Print Composer and in program window but when I open the exported .pdf the view is not correct. Shapes and boundary lines are shifted from the correct position on Google aerial imagery. No luck exporting as an image, printing as Adobe PDF etc.Help! [image]

[image: Left: correct locations, right: incorrect locations in exported .pdf]